# GCD of two numbers using Recursive function - What's Wrong?

Tags: c

> I am new to Programming, just a student.

I have written a program to calculate the GCD of two numbers using recursive function, but it's giving the correct answer for some, while it gives wrong answer for a few others. Kindly help me in identifying the problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int gcd(int,int,int)

int main(){
    int a,b,x,val;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    if(a>b)
        x=b;
    else
        x=a;

    val=gcd(a,b,x);
    printf("The GCD of the two numbers you entered is:%d",val);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int a,int b,int x){
    if(a%x==0){
        if (b%x==0)
            return x;
    }else
        return gcd(a,b,x-1);
}
```

For example, the program gives a wrong answer when first number = 69, second number = 65, whereas in some other cases it mysteriously gives the right answer.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your program line-by-line, to determine where its behaviour diverges from what you expect.  Alternatively, you could add a bunch of print statements to allow you to observe the values of variables on each recursion.

Comment: What is returned when a%x==0 but not b%x==0 ?

Comment: @LutherBlissett nothing is returned - and that's the mistake! Thanks.

Comment: This highlights why C is not a good language for beginners: this should have caused a compiler error, and would in most languages.

Comment: @Jules it does cause a error providing you are using a good compiler

Comment: Which compiler do you call a good compiler?  I've just compiled with gcc and it didn't give me an error.  To get an error out of it I have to use the rather unusual set of command line options "-Wall -Werror".  A beginner will not know they should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: consider the numbers `a=100` and `b=44`. When it reaches `x=25`, which divides 100, but not 44, your code doesn't have a proper path to take.

You are not taking all the conditions (paths) into consideration.

```
int gcd(int a,int b,int x){
    if(a%x==0){
        if (b%x==0)
           return x;
        else
           // ERROR ERROR ERROR, 
           // if the code reaches here, then it neither calls gcd recursively, 
           // nor does it return anything valueable
    }else
        return gcd(a,b,x-1);
}
```

You should change the code as below.

```
int gcd(int a,int b,int x){        
    if(a%x==0)
        if (b%x==0)
        {
            return x;
        }
    return gcd(a,b,x-1);
}
```

OR

```
int gcd(int a,int b,int x){
    if(a%x==0 && b%x==0) return x;        
    return gcd(a,b,x-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code path. Not all condition return an integer in the gcd function.
Which compiler are you using? It should give you a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int gcd(int a,int b,int x){
    if(a%x==0 && b%x==0) return x;        
    }else return gcd(a,b,x-1);
}
```

This catches both the modulus comparisons to 0 in one if statement, all conditions not falling within this get gcd calls.

Answer (score 0):

GCD of two numbers in C (the easiest way):

```c
while(secNum != 0) {
    Temp = fNum % secNum;
    fNum = secNum;
    secNum = Temp;
}

printf("GCD of the given two numbers : %d",fNum);
```